# Cannot read property 'firstname' of null in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to getting data from a form using react hook useState. But I'm facing the error `Cannot read property 'firstname' of null` while getting the value of input fields. Following is my registration and hook file.
**registration.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Container, Col, Form,
    FormGroup, Label, Input,
    Button,
} from 'reactstrap';
import useRegistrationForm from './hooks';


const Registration = () => {
    const register = () => {
        alert(`User Created!
               Name: ${inputs.firstName} ${inputs.lastName}
               Email: ${inputs.email}`);
    }
    const { inputs, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = useRegistrationForm(register);

    return (
        <div>
            <Container className="container">
                <h2>Registration</h2>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form">
                    <Col>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label className="label"> First Name</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="firstname" id="examplename" placeholder="Enter First Name"
                                onChange={handleInputChange} value={inputs.firstname}required></Input>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                 
                    <Button>Submit</Button>
                </Form>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Registration
```

Comment: I think we need to see the code for ```import useRegistrationForm from './hooks'```

Comment: In your `register` function, you are referring to `inputs` variable that doesn't necessarily exist in scope, where you are calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

In alert, you are using `inputs.firstName`.
Could it be the reason?
instead of `firstname`  >>   `firstName`